# deleting a specific lines in txt file then copy to a new txt file

Tags: java, file, copy, copy-paste, txt

i am having some problem in java, i wanted to remove number 5 to number 7 and save them into a new file called RevisedNumbers.txt, is there any way to do that? this is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Txt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
              File myObj = new File("Numbers1to10.txt");
              if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
              } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
              }
            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    try {
        Writer writer = new PrintWriter("Numbers1to10.txt");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            writer.write("Number" + i);
            writer.write("\r\n");
        }
        writer.close();
        File readFile = new File("Numbers1to10.txt");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(readFile);
        while (read.hasNextLine())
        System.out.println(read.nextLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    try {
          File myObj = new File("RevisedNumbers.txt");
          if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
          } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

the desired output on the new file will be

```
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4    
Number 8
Number 9
Number 10
```

Comment: firstly, closing files is incorrectly used, if you have Java 7+ version on your machine, use try-with-resources for closing files, otherwise close the files in the block finally; secondly, use `if` conditions to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be using an additional file.
While reading the contents of the first file ("Numbers1to10.txt"), if values are within 5 to 7, then write it into the second file ("RevisedNumbers.txt"), otherwise write it into the additional file.
Now the additional file contains values that you need in the first file. So copy all contents of the additional file into the first file.

Here is a sample code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileWriteMain {

    static void _write1to10(String locationWithFileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(locationWithFileName);

            boolean fileAlreadyExist = file.exists();
            if (fileAlreadyExist) {
                System.out.println("File already exists!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("New file has been created.");
            }

            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                fileWriter.write("Number " + i);
                fileWriter.append('\n');
            }
            fileWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static File _getFile(String locationWithFileName) {
        File file = null;
        file = new File(locationWithFileName);
        return file;
    }

    // it reads a file and print it's content in console
    static void _readFile(Scanner scanner) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String currLine = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(currLine);
        }
    }

    // read contents from sourceFile file and copy it into destinationFile
    static void _copyFromOneFileToAnother(File sourceFile, File destinationFile) throws IOException {

        FileWriter destFileWriter = new FileWriter(destinationFile);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(sourceFile);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String currLine = scanner.nextLine();

            destFileWriter.write(currLine);
            destFileWriter.append('\n');
        }
        destFileWriter.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String locationWithFileName = "E:\\FileWriteDemo\\src\\Numbers1to10.txt";   // give your file name including it's location
        _write1to10(locationWithFileName);

        System.out.println("File writing done!");

        File file1 = _getFile(locationWithFileName);
        try {

            // creating file 2
            String locationWithFileName2 = "E:\\FileWriteDemo\\src\\RevisedNumbers.txt";
            File file2 = _getFile(locationWithFileName2);
            FileWriter fileWriter2 = new FileWriter(file2);

            // creating a temporary file
            String tempFileLocationWithName = "E:\\FileWriteDemo\\src\\temporary.txt";
            File tempFile = _getFile(tempFileLocationWithName);
            FileWriter tempFileWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file1);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String currLine = scanner.nextLine();

                // split the word "Number" from integer
                String words[] = currLine.split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    // System.out.println(words[i]);
                    try {
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(words[i]);

                        if (num >= 5 && num <= 7) {
                            // writing to second file

                            fileWriter2.write(currLine);
                            fileWriter2.append('\n');
                        } else {
                            // writing to temporary file

                            tempFileWriter.write(currLine);
                            tempFileWriter.append('\n');
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // current word is not an integer, so don't have to do anything
                    }
                }

            }
            fileWriter2.close();
            tempFileWriter.close();


            _copyFromOneFileToAnother(tempFile, file1);

            System.out.println("\nContents of first file");
            _readFile(new Scanner(file1));
            
            System.out.println("\nContents of second file");
            _readFile(new Scanner(file2));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!
Happy coding.